# how to convert n-dash character to csv in php

Tags: php, encoding

I want to convert en-dash (–) as is when exporting to csv.

This is my header:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->filename"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
print "$header\n$data";
```

I already tried the following:

```
  mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-15' 'utf-8');
  // converts to â€“

  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
  // converts to small -

  iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $str);
  // ignores (–)

  htmlentities($items->campaign_name, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
  //converts to &ndash;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ISO-8859-*` doesn't have an en-dash at all. [`cp1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), the MS version that is often confused with [`8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), *does*.

```
$endash = '–';

var_dump(
    bin2hex($endash),
    bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($endash, 'cp1252', 'utf-8'))
);
```

Output:

```
string(6) "e28093"
string(2) "96"
```

Where `0x96` is the `cp1252` byte for an en-dash. The "bad" conversion you posted is simply the 3-byte UTF-8 sequence being passed through as-is and incorrectly displayed as `8859-1` or `cp1252`.

However I would strongly suggest that you simply make your life easier and configure your toolchain to work properly with UTF-8 instead as you're going to run into no end of troubles trying to represent symbols from incompatible single-byte encodings in a single document.